# Any one can help me in finding the points on flattened sphere

Tags: matlab, math

I have a flattened sphere x^2+(0.01)y^2+z^2=1. I want to find points on this sphere in Matlab. Please help I am new.

Comment: Well how about `x=0, y=0, z=1`? Or `x=0,  y=-10, z=0`?

Comment: In general the approach would be to generate random coordinates between upper and lower boundaries for x,y,z and then see which one satisfy the equation. Unfortunately floating point and testing for equality don't mix too well.

Comment: But I want to generate hundred of points

Comment: Well that's going to be tricky given that  floating point doesn't have infinite precision so the implicit rounding errors are going to spoil your day/checking for the equation. If you want points *inside* the sphere, then use `<` instead of `=` in your check, generate a bunch of numbers randomly as hinted at, filter them according to the *inequality* (`<` comparison) and you should be good to go.

Comment: actually I want to see plot of x^2+.01y^2+z^2=1 and cylinder x^2+z^2=1.4. if you have any idea please help

Answer (score 1):

This object is called an ellipsoid. Basically, you can sample its surface in the same way as you would sample a sphere. It may become a bit more difficult if you want to maintain a certain density distribution. However, if you just want some distribution, here is how you can do it:

```
phi := random number in [-pi, pi]
theta := random number in [-pi/2, pi/2]
x = sin phi cos theta
y = cos phi cos theta / sqrt(0.01)
z = sin theta
```

For the specified cylinder you would do:

```
phi := random number in [-pi, pi]
h := random number for the y-values
x = sin phi * sqrt(1.4)
y = h
z = cos phi * sqrt(1.4)
```

Comment: then how I distribute cylinder x^2+z^2=1.4